# render a dynamic number of highcharts charts is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

im trying this

```
$scope.chartsArray = [];
for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) { //i its the amount of charts to display
    document.getElementById("charts").innerHTML += '<div class="col-md-6" id="chart-' + j + '"></div>';
    $scope.tmp = new Highcharts.Chart({
        series: [1,2,3,4],
        chart: { type: 'column', renderTo: 'chart-' + j },
    });
    $scope.chartsArray.push($scope.tmp);
}
```

on this div

```
<div id="charts" class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:50px">  </div>
```

But when I load the charts only the last one loaded works properly, the other charts do not render the series and the interactions dont respond (like exporting or hiding the series).
Why is this?
do you guys know any other way to do this?

Comment: Try changing `$scope.tmp` to `var tmp` to scope each of the charts and instantiate them each separately. As of now you push a reference to the object multiple times, while changing the object.

Comment: This isn't how to do this at all. Let angular build the dom based on your data model. If this code runs in controller...the template may not event exist yet

Comment: @ryan03129 i already did that, nothing changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's bad practice to access and modify DOM from your angular controller. Use directive instead. Here is one for highcharts https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng